# boost binary serialization - why does bitwise copying only seem to work on collections?

Tags: c++, boost, binary, bit-manipulation, boost-serialization

Using boost serialization, I'm trying to find the best settings for fast binary serialization of big objects. My tests indicate that, for a structure tagged bitwise serializable, I only get better performance on arrays (and vectors), not on individual objects.

For instance, say I have this structure made up only of POD types

```
struct BigStruct
{
  double    m1;
  long long m2;
  float     m3;
  // ...
  bool      m499;
  short     m500;
};

namespace boost
{
  namespace serialization
  {
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ioArchive, BigStruct& ioStruct, const unsigned int iVersion)
    {
      ioArchive & ioStruct.m1;
      ioArchive & ioStruct.m2;
      ioArchive & ioStruct.m3;
      // ...
      ioArchive & ioStruct.m499;
      ioArchive & ioStruct.m500;
    }
  }
}

#include <boost/serialization/is_bitwise_serializable.hpp>
BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(BigStruct);
```

Then, serializing a single object

```
{
  std::ofstream outStream(tmpFolder + "/BinarySerializationOfBigStruct.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive binOutArchive(outStream, boost::archive::no_header);

  BigStruct bigStruct;

  std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();
  binOutArchive << bigStruct;
  std::clock_t c_end = std::clock();

  // ...compute elapsed time...
}
```

takes about 7 times longer than serializing an array of 1 object

```
{
  std::ofstream outStream(tmpFolder + "/BinarySerializationOfBigStructArray.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive binOutArchive(outStream, boost::archive::no_header);

  BigStruct bigStructArray[1];

  std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();    
  binOutArchive << bigStructArray;
  std::clock_t c_end = std::clock();

  // ...compute elapsed time...
}
```

Am I missing something? Is this an oversight in boost serialization?

BTW I'm using boost v1.53.